# NAT with strongswan - howto?

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, nat, strongswan

[Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbMi7.png)

I have the following setup where Office 1 and Office 2 have the same IP address range (192.168.0.0/16) and both are using strongSwan running on Ubuntu VM (with two NICs one connected to LAN (eth1 192.168.1.4) and one in the DMZ (eth0 192.168.0.4)) which connects to CLOUD network shown in the diagram with S2S VPN connection. Both connections are up from office 1 and office 2 to cloud.

Because both offices have the same IP address range, Office 1 can only reach to Cloud network. If bring down the S2S VPN connection from Office 1 then I can reach from office 2 to the cloud network.

As far as I know this can be solved if I do some NAT on one or both Offices. Can someone advise me on how to configure the NAT on strongswan machine so that when the traffic is sent to the cloud over the VPN Tunnel to look like it is coming from a network address space different(let's say 172.16.0.0/16) than 192.168.0.0/16.

Appreciate your help here in advance.

Comment: The [ikev2/net2net-same-nets](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-same-nets/) test scenario uses the iptables `NETMAP` target for this. Also see the [notes regarding those scenarios](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConfigurationExamplesNotes) on the wiki.